# How to allow an identifer which can start with a digit without causing MismatchedTokenException

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I want to match the following input:

```
statement span=1m 0_dur=12
```

with the following grammar:

```
options {
language = Java;
output=AST;
ASTLabelType=CommonTree; 
}

statement :'statement' 'span' '=' INTEGER 'm' ident '=' INTEGER;

INTEGER 
:   DIGIT+
    ;

ident : IDENT | 'AVG' | 'COUNT';

IDENT
:   (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')+  ;

WHITESPACE  
:   ( ' '
    | '\t'
    | '\r'
    | '\n'
    ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

fragment 
LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;

fragment 
DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

but it cause an error:

MismatchedTokenException : line 1:15 mismatched input '1m' expecting '\u0004'

Does anyone has any idea how to solve this?

THanks
Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your grammar is context sensitive, even at the lexical analyser(Tokenizer) level. The string "1m" is recognized as IDENT, not INTEGER followed by 'm'. You either redefine your syntax, or use predicated parsing, or embed Java code in your grammar to detect the context (e.g. If the number is presented after "span" followed by "=", then parse it as INTEGER).